# Hum/buzz from PC speakers, but stops when the mouse moves?

Tags: mouse, desktop-computer, speakers

I have some old PC speakers plugged into my laptop and I get a fairly constant buzz from them. This is perhaps not that surprising considering they are old and cheap.

*But* I've noticed whenever I move the mouse, it stops, then re-starts about one second after I stop moving the mouse. I'm curious why.

Some things I've already tested:

- Moving my hand on the desk or simply resting my hand on the mouse doesn't do it, only moving the mouse... I wondered if the movement of the mouse was interfering with resonance.

  - Resting my hand on the speakers also doesn't change anything.
  - Typing on the keyboard or other normal actions don't seem to do anything
  - Moving the mouse off the desk onto my leg or other surface *does* cause the same effect, so again it's not the physical movement of the mouse on the desk

This is really a question of curiosity not a problem per se. I don't know if this is really the best SE site for it but hopefully someone here can answer or point me at the right place.

Comment: Is your mouse wireless? My guess would be that the OS slows down mouse-requests when there is a second of no movement, and the slowed-down request frequency is in the hearable range (implying that while you _move_ the mouse there is a buzz in the high ultrasound range, which you cannot hear and/or the speaker cannot produce)

Comment: No it is wired. But that's a very interesting idea.